# YII2 Redirect to backend after user registration from frontend

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-url-manager

After installation of advance template in yii2, I got a user registration from at the frontend but I want it to redirect to backend after registration. How can that be done???

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome(); // I WANT TO CHANGE THIS TO REDIRECT TO LOCALHOST/MYAPP/BACKEND/WEB
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**UPDATE**
here is the urlmanager

```
    'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
    'urlManagerBackend' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost/ncddp/backend/web/index.php',
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure separate `urlManager` component in `frontend` for `backend`:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
'urlManagerBackend' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'baseUrl' => 'http://admin.site.com',
],
```

Put in `components` section in application config.

Then you can use it like that:

```
Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl(...);
```

Usage with redirect:

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl(...));
```

**Related links:**

- [Issue on Github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1578)
- [Url Manager component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html)
- [Routing and URL Creation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

Comment: How to user this `Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl();` in the redirect?

Comment: Updated the answer with information how to do that.

Comment: after setting the `enablePrettyUrl` to `true` application can no longer recognize `http://localhost/ncddp/frontend/web/site/signup` it returns 404

Comment: It's just for example purposes. Remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: I'm sorry. What should be placed inside `createUrl(...)`? I tried `return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl('index'));` but the url goes to `http://localhost/ncddp/frontend/web/index.php?r=index` which is 404... also still at frontend.

Comment: Am I correct with this `return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl('index'));` I have change the urlManager but the error is still the same. URL goes to `http://localhost/ncddp/frontend/web/index.php?r=index` after registration. I updated my question above.

Comment: You need to configure url for backend in your web server. You specified path, not url.

Comment: I'm getting more confused. What do you mean by configure url for backend in web server? I'm in localhost. How do I do that?

Comment: Try to specify `'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost/myapp/backend/web'` and then create url like that: `Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl(['site/index'])`.

Comment: `return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl('site'));    `Still the same. After registration browser redirects here `http://localhost/ncddp/frontend/web/index.php?r=site`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76410/discussion-between-arogachev-and-nerison).

Comment: **1)** `'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost/myapp/backend/web'`. You need url to backend, not frontend. **2)** `Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl(['site/index'])`. Please check everything accurately again, I tested it and it works just fine.

Comment: I did that already but still the same. I have tried configuring both url managers for backend and frontend but still no changes.

Comment: @arogachev can you tell me , where to place this url manager code? please share file path.