# YII2 Redirect to another namespace

Tags: php, web, yii2

So I'm trying to implement a rerouting when the user tries to access the address ".../frontend/web/admin" to ".../backend/web/admin". Any tips on how to do it? So far I've been trying with the redirect without any result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YII2 Redirect to backend after user registration from frontend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888430/yii2-redirect-to-backend-after-user-registration-from-frontend)

Comment: Still does not work :/.

Comment: Try better ..   ... Try ...eventually take a look at this too  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1578

Comment: Or try this  .. is a my old answer  about this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453465/yii2-link-frontend-to-backend

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include your webserver settings here to get clear answer. Basically if you want to redirect from one app to another I have included most popular cases:

1) By default you need to setup FE app to one domain, BE to subdomain or a new domain. If you use subdomain you can use "share a cookie" technique to start a new session on you subdomain (e.g. use db as a session storage)

2) if you have diff domain you can use direct link with auth. like we do when we want to verify user's email, e.g. http://backend.com/admin/?authme=secret_key